# updates to faulty future dates in Database

Tags: java, oracle

I am updating date in oracle 11 g using JDBC for this I read dates in one file and update date in DB to this date , at the end  some dates updated correctly while some date updates to future date (dates in 2015/2016).Even file can not contain date greater than sysdate. When I print date before updating it print correctly but when I check in Database it shows wrong date .I am using following query

```
   update data set IBOOLEAN1=?,LASTACTIVITYDATE=?,OPENDATE=? where SEMAIL=? and SEGMENTNAME='EDU'  
  prepareStatement.setInt(1, 1);
  DateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
   Date openDate = dFormat.parse(oldStringDate);
  timeStm = new Timestamp(newDate.getTime());
  prepareStatement.setTimestamp(2, timeStm);
  prepareStatement.setTimestamp(3, timeStm);
  prepareStatement.setString(4, emailAddress);
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem..??

Comment: could you please show us some input dates and the value that gets inserted?

Comment: in your code you use newDate as parameter, which is not defined in this code fragment. please add some more context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves the issue since you need to provide more details, but this :

`SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");`

is incorrect. Since, `MM` means `MONTH NUMBER`, and the `MINUTES` in the time part has format `MI`.

**Update** Added test case

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'mm') mm,
  2         TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'mi') mi
  3    FROM dual
  4  /

MM MI
-- --
10 17
```

Comment: no, the format string seems correct, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @1010, can you please show how `MM` format could be used for `MINUTES`? AFAIK, `MM` is a format mask for months and `MI` is for minutes.

Comment: for SimpleDateFormat MM means Month in year, mm means minutes (not MI). the format string is on the java side

Comment: I have checked in database but some date updated correctly as in file no minute and month changed.